# Profile/account REST API naming convention

Tags: php, web-services, api, rest, http

I have tried to search the net, but haven't found any example of best practice url naming convention for the following requests.
My API allows user to log into the system, retrieve secure token which can be used to access private data over the HTTPS.

So there following features will be support by API :

1. Auth. Simple authentification. `/api/auth` will be used to log into the system first time and get token in response or refresh expired token if required.
2. View profile data (first name,last name, phone number ....). What is the best way to form url for this resource.  I have several ideas : `/api/users/me/profile OR /api/users/{id}/profile`. In the first case our client (REST API consumer) doesn't need to know exact ID of user, when user tries to access this resource it checks if token is valid,if passed user name exists and tied to the token, and than just returns data based on this information. In the second case we have to know exact ID of user, of course this ID can be returned in response to the auth.
3. Also other methods like `/api/user/me/orderlist, /api/user/me/someuserspecificinfo`.
4. What about making an order. I have read the if you need to create new resource you have to use POST, if update - PUT. How my url should look like ?

   `/api/neworder (parameters in post body), /api/user/neworder , /api/orders (just with post method)`

   .......

Please suggest what the commonly used naming convention for such resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resource URIs should be more or less constant, and the HTTP verb determines what action is performed, eg:

`/api/orders`:

- `GET`: list orders
- `POST`: create new order

`/api/orders/{order-id}`;

- `GET`: retrieve info about an order
- `POST`: create an order with the specified ID
- `PUT`: modify an order
- `DELETE`: remove an order

Putting function-like names in your REST API like `/api/user/neworder` is a great way to attract the ire of REST fundamentalists.

Comment: Thank you a lot for explanation, please suggest what to do about second question ? How to form URI for user profile ?

Comment: @CROSP looks fine? Most APIs I've worked with use the "kitchen sink" approach and just serve every single scrap of data in the `/api/resource/{id}` endpoint because many seem to think that making more than one HTTP request is "wasteful", but other than that there's no reason you can't split up the user info into more bite-sized chunks like this.

Comment: Yes your approach is great, I wonder how to get current user or it is redundant, use just /users/profile or /users/{id}/profile or /users/me/profile. The only one thing I am worrying about is I have to know exact user id or it is okey ? If I will try to access other user information, token check will fail

Comment: @CROSP REST isn't a strict standard, it's more of a style. You can certainly implement a `/users/me` resource, but REST purists want the endpoints to be stateless [think "no cookies, no sessions"] so unless you're including some other information in the request headers denoting your identity you're likely imposing state*ful*ness on your endpoint. If it were me I'd simply store `$me = '{user-id}';` in the client.